# Optimally replacing multi-line substring in bash for non-greedy matching?

Tags: string, bash, replace, split

There are a lot of different solutions for string replacement on a single-line basis but I'm curious as to what the most efficient method is to perform a multi-line replacement using only bash builtins.

I am using the following solution using bash's builtin regex which works fine if there is only one match:

```
read -r -d '' to_search <<'EOF'
1
2
3
-
1
2
3
-
1
2
3
EOF

read -r -d '' to_find <<'EOF'
1
2
3
EOF

read -r -d '' to_replace <<'EOF'
a
b
c
EOF

[[ $to_search =~ (.*)($to_find)(.*) ]] &&
   echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$to_replace${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

This can also work if I want all matches replaced as I can loop until there is no match. But it does not provide a solution which is non-greedy as bash's regex builtin does not support the `?` operator.

For example, because the matching is greedy, the output will only consider the last match instead of stopping at the first. For example:

```
1
2
3
-
1
2
3
-
a
b
c
```

One solution might be to split the input and match string into arrays and stepping through them in a loop to find a match but this might not be optimal.

I would welcome alternative solutions for reference but the question specifically is to solve this using only bash builtins. This could be solved by passing the string to Python or Perl but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answers are welcome for alternatives using common utils (sed/grep/awk) are welcome for reference and comparison but will not be accepted as it does not answer this specific question. Additional brownie points for a solution which works for older bash environments which do not provide regex facilities.

Note that this might look easy at first for sed and grep but both of these tools only perform matches on individual lines and are not appropriate for multi-line matches.

Comment: wrong! `sed` is really capable of handling multi-line matches, even-though you won't often see such usages. See the `sed` commands with upper case letters [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/appa_03.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it involves plain text search or glob patterns then BASH's string substitution works fine:

```
echo "${to_search//$to_find/$to_replace}"

a
b
c
-
a
b
c
-
a
b
c
```

---

**EDIT:** As per your edited example that contains glob character `*`, you can use this awk search loop using `index` function:

```
read -r -d '' to_search <<'EOF'
*
1
2
3
*
1
2
3
*
1
2
3
EOF

read -r -d '' to_find <<'EOF'
*
1
2
3
EOF

read -r -d '' to_replace <<'EOF'
a
b
c
EOF

awk -v s="$to_search" -v f="$to_find" -v r="$to_replace" 'BEGIN {
   while(p=index(s, f)) s = substr(s, 1, p-1) r substr(s, p+length(f)); print s}'

a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

PS: Note that following `bash` *pattern substitution* will also work by escaping each `*`:

```
echo "${to_search//${to_find//\*/\\*}/$to_replace}"

a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

Comment: To match only first, use: `echo "${to_search/$to_find/$to_replace}"`

Comment: I'm getting an odd result when I introduce `*` as part of the string. It replaces all adjacent instances and merges them: https://pastebin.com/uziCUK9q

Comment: The expected output should not merge the results. I've revised my pastebin link. It works as expected if I use some other character such as `-`.

Comment: The requirements for a successful answer "is to solve this using only bash builtins".

Comment: There is a **bash pattern substitution** option in my answer.

Comment: And it has issues with the `-` character and possibly others, as I responded previously.

Comment: Why are you asking for a comprehensive sample input? Just solve the one provided in the question.

Comment: Bash solution already does that, it matches your expected output shown in pastebin link.

Comment: Accepting this as it does answer the question and additional requirements such as complexities involving globing characters and other untested input is out-of-scope. Thank you for your patience.